# Mangaing scheduled tasks

Tags: database, algorithm, optimization, data-structures

I want to crete backend service in 'spring boot' that is responsible for managing schedualed actvities. The problem i encounter is that activities cannot overlap nor can there be any empty timeframe bettwen them.

I want to perform add and edit operations that can potenialy crete overlap on already existing records, in that case i want to modify start and end of neighbourng activites or delte actvities contained bettween start and stop. How to effectivly manage such use-cases:

1. Is there any data structure that can help or is it more efficient to perform custom sql queries in repostory?
2. Are there any algorithms or design patterns for such usecases?

The way i do it now is I creted set of conditions(for exmaple, searching neighboring activities that overlap) and get record form databse, modify them and then save them. I feel this is not most effective way. And what would happen if i wnated to modify multiple records at a time.

I also came across idea of SEGMENT TREES, but i dont know how to practicly implement it in spring backend. Should i get all records from databse and put it into this data structure, is this optimal?
Or should i shomehow modify entities?